# Is there a way to save my firebase users profile pictures and display later?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app has groups with different users (members) in each.
I want to save users profile pictures so I can display to other users
the members in each group.

I have been looking for answer for a couple of weeks. Could not find
similar question. I have some experience in firebase and android.

Here is the code:

```
private void saveUserProfilePic(){
    Uri photoUrl = thisUser.getPhotoUrl();


    if(photoUrl != null) {

        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(thisUser.getUid());
        fileReference.putFile(photoUrl)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tries to save the link of the image in a database and get it later?

Comment: I did try. It did not work for me. However I did solved it with other method. The thing is that I have problem only with users profile images. Other images from the user phone I manage to upload to firebase storage and display.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to upload a file for which you have the URL. You need to use the UploadTask for that. The best way would be to create an InputStream from the URL and then create an uploadTask. Something like below.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)photoUrl.openConnection();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
```

or you can create a BufferedInputStream
    InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

Now you can create an uploadTask.

```
UploadTask uploadTask = fileReference.putStream(stream);
```

Now you can use your old code.

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can, I found the way.

1. create fields:

```
private CircleImageView civ;  //its like image view

private StorageReference storageReference;
```

2. in `onCreate()`:

```
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("your_firbase_ reference");
```

3. use the following lines:

```
StorageReference storageRef = storageReference;
Glide.with(<your activity>.this)
   .load(storageRef)
   .into(civ);
```

I am using the glide library and this way is for firebase projects.